# How to access arguments from method called with __getattr__?

Tags: python, oop, methods

I have the following object:

```py
class Api(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __getattr__(self, fname):
        # I cannot access the parameters of "fname"
        print("__getattr__ : ", fname)
```

When doing:

```py
>>> api = Api()
>>> api.somefunction("foo", "bar", namedparam="baz")
__getattr__ :  somefunction
```

I cannot retrieve the "foo", "bar" and "baz" arguments given to the `somefunction` function. How can I retrieve them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to do so with the `func.partial` function:

```py
class Api(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def xcall(self, fname, *args, **kwargs):
        print("xcall", fname, args, kwargs)

    def __getattr__(self, fname):
        print("__getattr__ : ", fname)
        return partial(self.xcall, fname)
```

Calling it:

```
>>> api = Api()
>>> api.somefunction("foo", "bar", namedparam="baz")
__getattr__ :  somefunction
xcall somefunction ('foo', 'bar') {'namedparam': 'baz'}
```

What it does is that it returns a callable `partial(self.xcall, fname)` that will then take the arguments. The `__getattr__` function only handles the "dot part" from the call, not the passing of arguments.